# How to send push notification to a specific group of user in firebase

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send push notifications to a specific group of user in firebase.For example, in the sign up form of a app in the pet field a user put pet type as dog.now I want to send push notification to the user who have dog.
anybody please suggest me how can I do this with firebase?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to specify audience in analytics who's pet contains dog.

[image]
*this screenshot is example of mine*

Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) offers three different types of targets, which allows you to send push notifications to a specified user group. The three types of targets are: user segment, topic, and single device.

[image]
*this screenshot is example of mine*

In User segment, you can choose an app for sending out push notifications. Click "AND" to add more filter rules.

In audience - you can send push notifications to the users who's pet have dog.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code :

```
public class NotifyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Constants {

        private Activity activity;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<Notify> notifyList;

        ImageLoader imageLoader = App.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        public NotifyListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Notify> notifyList) {

            this.activity = activity;
            this.notifyList = notifyList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return notifyList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int location) {

            return notifyList.get(location);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return position;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {

            public TextView notifyTitle;
            public TextView notifyTimeAgo;
            public CircularImageView notifyAuthor;
            public CircularImageView notifyType;

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

            if (inflater == null) {

                inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }

            if (convertView == null) {

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notify_list_row, null);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.notifyAuthor = (CircularImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.notifyAuthor);
                viewHolder.notifyType = (CircularImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.notifyType);
                viewHolder.notifyTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.notifyTitle);
                viewHolder.notifyTimeAgo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.notifyTimeAgo);

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

            } else {

                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            if (imageLoader == null) {

                imageLoader = App.getInstance().getImageLoader();
            }

            viewHolder.notifyTitle.setTag(position);
            viewHolder.notifyTimeAgo.setTag(position);
            viewHolder.notifyAuthor.setTag(position);
            viewHolder.notifyType.setTag(position);
            viewHolder.notifyAuthor.setTag(R.id.notifyAuthor, viewHolder);

            final Notify notify = notifyList.get(position);

            viewHolder.notifyType.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (notify.getType() == NOTIFY_TYPE_LIKE) {

                viewHolder.notifyTitle.setText(activity.getText(R.string.label_gcm_like));
                viewHolder.notifyType.setImageResource(R.drawable.notify_like);

                viewHolder.notifyAuthor.setImageResource(R.drawable.notify_like);

            } else if (notify.getType() == NOTIFY_TYPE_COMMENT) {

                viewHolder.notifyTitle.setText(activity.getText(R.string.label_gcm_comment));
                viewHolder.notifyType.setImageResource(R.drawable.notify_comment);

                viewHolder.notifyAuthor.setImageResource(R.drawable.notify_comment);

            } else if (notify.getType() == NOTIFY_TYPE_COMMENT_REPLY) {

                viewHolder.notifyTitle.setText(activity.getText(R.string.label_gcm_comment_reply));
                viewHolder.notifyType.setImageResource(R.drawable.notify_reply);

                viewHolder.notifyAuthor.setImageResource(R.drawable.notify_reply);

            } else {

                viewHolder.notifyTitle.setText(activity.getText(R.string.label_follow_you));
                viewHolder.notifyType.setImageResource(R.drawable.notify_follower);

                viewHolder.notifyAuthor.setImageResource(R.drawable.notify_follower);
            }

            viewHolder.notifyTimeAgo.setText(notify.getTimeAgo());

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd typically use topic messaging for that. With topics your user would subscribe to the topic `pet_type_dog`. On Android this would look like this:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("pet_type_dog");
```

Then you send a message to all users with pet type equal to dog. With the JavaScript Admin SDK that would look like:

```
admin.messaging().sendToTopic("pet_type_dog", {
  notification: {
    title: "Monday message for dog lovers",
    body: "Today's special dog is Dee Dee from SF."
  }
}).then(function(response) {
    // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
    // contents of response.
    console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error sending message:", error);
  })
```

Comment: I am going to make an blood related Android app......a user will signup filling his blood group and his location. there will be also an request part in the firebase data base.when a user request for a spefic group of blood in  a specific location,a push notification should be automatically  sent to the users who have that specific blood group in that location.I want to firebase cloud functions and push notification for that.please suggest me how can I do that.

Comment: My answer shows the approach and most of the code you need for that. Please try the solution and tell what part you're having trouble with.